# $ne query not working with mongoose but working in mongoshell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I execute this mongoose query

```
FinancedProject.find({_id:{$ne:fb.financedProjects.financedProjectId}).exec( callback);
```

where fb is an object like this

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("54das4da9dsa9d4ad4a9");
    name: "some",
    financedProjects: [
       {registry:"147", financedProjectId:ObjectId("13da4sd4sa48da4dsa")},
       {registry:"189", financedProjectId:ObjectId("5d5asd5a4sd5ada5sd")}
    ]
{
```

the result is undefined and when I execute it in the mongoshell the results are the expected

Comment: Is the result `undefined` or an empty `array`?

Comment: Undefined, and if i set on mongoose debug to true, it does not show me the query

Comment: If result is undefined probably there was an error. What's in the err parameter of the callback?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `financedProjects` is an `array` you have to address the element with `[]` like:

```
FinancedProject.find({
    _id: {
        $ne: fb.financedProjects[0|.financedProjectId
    }
}).exec( callback );
```

**EDIT:**

mongoose ist JavaScript, so it follows the rules of JavaScript. `fb.financedProjects` is an `array`. So if you use the expression `fb.financedProjects.financedProjectId` this is evaluated to `undefined` by the JavaScript interpreter, because there is no `financedProjectId` property within that array (arrays have `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,... as properties). So mongoose does get `{ $ne: undefined }` and has no chance to recognize that you meant the property `financedProjectId` of the array **elements**.

To achieve what you want, you can do this:

```
var arr = [];
for( var i=0; i<fb.financedProjects.length; i+=1 ) {
    arr.push( fb.financedProjects[i|.financedProjectId );
}
FinancedProject.find({
    $not: {
        _id: {
            $in: arr
        }
    }
}).exec( callback );
```

Comment: That work for one case, but I want to compare it to all others.As I said, in mongoshell it works perfectly.I think that the problem is in the mongoose implementation of $ne when it compares docs inside an array

Comment: Where do you get `fb` from (mongoose and shell). Please show more code.

Comment: Thank you. The problem, as you said, is that financedProjects in JS. Thank you so much